# Unable to get Hot Module Replacement working on different port

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpack-hmr, hot-module-replacement

So currently I am working on an .NET MVC application where a portion of the app is a portal where the client is rendered completely using reactjs.

Basically I have an index.cshtml file for my portal that looks something like this:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>User Portal</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script src="http://localhost:3000/bundle.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

and my client side reactjs app running concurently on port:3000 using an express server. I access my main MVC app through localhost:53079. I was wondering if it was possible to get hot module reloading to work on port 53079 since this is how I access my application?

My webpack.config.dev.js looks like this:

```
export default {
  debug: true,
  devtool: 'inline-source-map',
  noInfo: false,
  entry: [
    'eventsource-polyfill', // necessary for hot reloading with IE
    'webpack-hot-middleware/client?reload=true', //note that it reloads the page if hot module reloading fails.
    path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/index')
  ],
  target: 'web',
  output: {
    path: __dirname + '/dist', // Note: Physical files are only output by the production build task `npm run build`.
    publicPath: 'http://localhost:3000/',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  devServer: {
    contentBase: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src')
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin()
  ],
  module: {
    //.....
  }
};
```

I have tried modifying the port number in devServer, as well as in the output path without any luck. I've also been able to find very little reading on how to configure hmr port numbers. Currently my console is being littered by the following error message:

> EventSource's response has a MIME type ("text/html") that is not "text/event-stream". Aborting the connection.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?  I have the same issue with Angular 2 after upgrading to .net core 2. 

What is happening on my end is that the routing is picking up the request for __webpack_hmr and the SPA fallback route kicks in and routes it to index, so the request for the hmr is actually returning a webpage,hence the 'text/html'.  Be damned if I can figure out why or how to fix it though!

Comment: Yep same thing here... Unfortunately have not been able to find a solution on this and have pretty much given up on HMR for concurrent development for the time being.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, you need to set the options to point at your hmr endpoint.

```
app.UseWebpackDevMiddleware(new WebpackDevMiddlewareOptions {
          HotModuleReplacement = true,
          HotModuleReplacementEndpoint = "/dist/__webpack_hmr"
        });
```